# Python copy parts of dictionary into a new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which looks like this:

```
old_dict={"payment_amt": "20",
          "chk_nr": "321749",
          "clm_list": {"dtl": [{"clm_id": "1A2345", "name": "John"},
                               {"clm_id": "9999", "name": "Jack"}]}}
```

I need to parse the above and store it as:

```
{"payment_amt": "20",
 "clm_list": {"dtl": [{"clm_id": "1A2345"},
                      {"clm_id": "9999"}]}}
```

Is there a right pythonic way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: This is not really _"parsing"_. And there is no elegant way to do it because the structure is complex. You could make a dictionary comprehension, but it is a dictionary in a list in a dictionary in a dictionary, so it is going to be ugly.

Comment: What is the basis of your "parsing"? Is it to remove all keys `"chk_nr"` and `"name"` with their values and leave the rest, or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would go with a straightforward copy of the exact keys you want to keep in the example you posted (see Rob's answer), if the input is always exactly like you listed. Keep it simple.

However, if you can't rely on the input to always have the same exact structure, you can still reduce it to only include the expected keys with a recursive function which uses dict comprehensions.

```
old_dict = {"payment_amt": "20", 
            "chk_nr": "321749", 
            "clm_list": {"dtl": [{"clm_id": "1A2345", "name": "John"}, 
                                 {"clm_id": "9999", "name": "Jack"}]}}

keep = ["payment_amt", "clm_list", "dtl", "clm_id"]

def recursively_prune_dict_keys(obj, keep):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: recursively_prune_dict_keys(v, keep) for k, v in obj.items() if k in keep}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [recursively_prune_dict_keys(item, keep) for item in obj]
    else:
        return obj

new_dict = recursively_prune_dict_keys(old_dict, keep)
print new_dict
```

output:

```
{'clm_list': {'dtl': [{'clm_id': '1A2345'}, {'clm_id': '9999'}]}, 'payment_amt': '20'}
```

Comment: Nice. Similar to my solution, and a bit simpler; but this might fail if some key with a common name, like `name`, `id`, or `value`, is to be kept for some elements and removed for others.

Comment: I figure when the input template is known and consistent, we don't need a fancy recursive function, and Rob's answer is the best. I was going for known tags in arbitrary arrangements. For example if dtl never appeared, but instead clm_list just had a list of dicts, mine would handle it (although the output would still not have a dtl). But I like tobias_k's also because if you have an input template, you can reuse it in functions that tests for a template match, or to populate the template from other arbitrary sources.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many "*right pythonic ways to do it*".
Here is one such way:

```
old_dict = {
    "payment_amt": "20",
    "chk_nr": "321749",
    "clm_list": {
        "dtl": [
            {"clm_id": "1A2345", "name": "John"},
            {"clm_id": "9999", "name": "Jack"}]}}

new_dict = {
    'payment_amt': old_dict['payment_amt'],
    'clm_list': {
        'dtl': [{
            'clm_id': dtl['clm_id']} for dtl in old_dict['clm_list']['dtl']]}}

assert new_dict == {
    "payment_amt": "20",
    "clm_list": {"dtl": [{"clm_id": "1A2345"}, {"clm_id": "9999"}]}}
```

Comment: Why to import `copy` when you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: I was going to `copy.deepcopy()`, but then I saw all of the constraints. Removing it now.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "template" dictionary/list/whatever and define a recursive method that traverses both the input object (some sort of nested list/dictionary thing) and the template in parallel and just keeps those elements that are in the respective place in the template. In a basic version, this could look like this (but could certainly be extended to cover more cases):

```
def prune_dict(obj, template):
    if template is None:
        return obj
    if isinstance(template, dict):
        return {key: prune_dict(obj[key], template[key]) for key in template}
    if isinstance(template, list):
        return [prune_dict(x, template[0]) for x in obj]
```

Here, `template` is assumed to be another dictionary or list. `None` is used to denote "leafs" in the structure. For `list`, the template is assumed to hold only one element, that is used as template for all the list's elements. For `dict`, it will retain all those values that are represented in the template.

Applied to your use case:

```
>>> tmpl = {"payment_amt": None, "clm_list": {"dtl": [{"clm_id": None}]}}
>>> prune_dict(old_dict, tmpl)
{'clm_list': {'dtl': [{'clm_id': '1A2345'}, {'clm_id': '9999'}]}, 'payment_amt': '20'}
```